# What is the most efficient way to use one component for multiple pages in Angular?

Tags: angular

I currently trying to build a website where the about us, services and contact us all have the same format.

The format goes like this:

- A photo for the banner
- A main heading
- A description

The data will be retrieved from an API. Instead of having to create 3 components, I want to use 1 component and just change the data when the user clicks on the page. For example, If the user clicks on 'About Us' it shows the about us data using a component but when the click 'Contact Us' it uses the same component but different data.

What is the most efficient way of achieving this? Because I was wondering if my website has 20-30 pages and follows the same format what would be the best method instead of generating a component for each page.

Wireframes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some images, wireframes, designs would help us give you proper advise. Because, from the details you have provided, I can only advise you to create components basing on functionality instead of the description. i.e create components for sections of the pages that look or are the same. It is a bad idea to just use one component and have everything inside that, specially considering SEO.

Comment: @Link I've just added some wireframes showing what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the exact same data (including the text and paragraphs and what not) and structure, with only 3 different pages, you can simply just use an `*ngIf` structural directive to switch up the main heading. But, I'm pretty sure that you're content will obviously be different for all 3 pages - AboutUs, Services and Contact Us.

**My understanding from your wireframes:**

**About Us**
This one will probably have some images and text content

**Services**
This too will have some text content with a possibility of some images

**Contact Us**
Although in the wireframe, this just shows plain text content, from what I understand of `Contact Us` pages, this will most likely need to use either Reactive or Template Driven forms in order to collect some user data so they can send you whatever message they want to send to you etc.

While it is 100% possible for you to have everything inside one single component, that has so many downsides when you actually want to deploy this app into production, specially if you want it to be scalable.

Some of the downsides are:

- Code will be less readable with a lot of spaghetti code.
- Code will be less maintainable.
- It will be almost impossible for you to scale up with say 20-30 different pages.
- You will not be able to have proper routing.
- No Feature Modules for Lazy Loading.
- Large bundle size due to lack of Lazy Loading.

The approach I would suggest here would be to:

- Since the banner image will be present in every page, have a separate component for that, where you can fetch and display the banner image basing on the page/route you're visiting using (ActivatedRoute).
- You can essentially keep the main heading inside the above component as well.
- Now for the pages that will have the exact same structure with different content, you can have a single component that will again use `ActivatedRoute` to see which route you're visiting and change the content accordingly, this will be your content component, you can simply use structural directives like `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` to achieve this.
- One way to do this is to not have your html text content directly in the component template, and instead have it in the `.ts` file using string literals stored in class level variables that you can show and hide by setting the `[innerHTML]` directive. However, with this you will not be able to use the AOT compiler with `ng build --prod` and will have to use `ng build` with JIT compiler. So, as long as your app is small it is okay, but if you have a lot of pages, it is better to have the HTML sitting inside the `template file` instead of the `.ts` file.
- For the components that require you to have a form like a Contact Form you can either have a separate component containing the contact form which you will create using `Reactive Forms or Template Driven Forms` and show that component within your content component.
- If you have a footer, you should create a separate component for that as well.

**Another approach, with feature modules & lazy loading:**
However, if your website will have a lot of pages, it is better that you divide your website into several components and create feature modules for components that fall under a group, and then lazy load these feature modules in order to reduce your bundle size of the main.js file making your website's initial bundle size much compact with a smaller footprint.

This would be an overall better approach in terms of scalability as well. But, since you only have 3 components right now, you can go with the above approach as well. In the end, you will need to pick one of these approaches basing on what you're looking to do with this application, how large it is gonna end up being etc.

Since this is an open ended question, I can only give you answer basing on what I might do if I have to work on an application with the requirements that I understand from the wireframes, hope this can be of use.